# Allocating NSString repeatedly in a loop while avoiding memory leak

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, nsstring

I am playing around with `NSOperationQueue` in order to run some code in the background and have it update a `UILabel`. Here's the `viewDidLoad`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

  NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(counterTask) object:nil];
  [queue addOperation:operation];
}
```

And here's the method called as the invocation operation:

```
- (void)counterTask {
  for (int i=0; i<5000000; i++) {
    if (i % 100 == 0) {
      [self.firstLabel performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setText:)
                       withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i]
                       waitUntilDone:YES];
    }
  }

  [self.firstLabel performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setText:) withObject:@"finished." waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

As the loop counts up, and more and more `@"%d"` `NSString`s are created, the memory usage naturally goes up. Once the loop finishes however, the memory doesn't seem to deallocate. I expected the memory to fall as the `setText:` message uses new instances of `NSString` and releases the old ones.

If I change the loop condition to `i<5000000*2`, the memory usage is roughly double by the end – so it's definitely something happening on each iteration causing the leak.

Why is memory leaking here?

EDIT: Forgot to mention that I'm using ARC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ARC doesn't remove retain / release / *autorelease*, it just controls the calling of these methods. You can add your own autorelease pool into your loop to force cleanup as it goes:

```
for (int i=0; i<5000000; i++) {
    if (i % 100 == 0) {
        @autoreleasepool {
            [self.firstLabel performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setText:)
                                              withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i]
                                           waitUntilDone:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding the @autoreleasepool here doesn't seem to be causing the memory to remain stable as the loop iterates; it continues to grow and not fall back after the final iteration.

Comment: In Instruments, verify what objects are retained and look at what is holding references to them. Do you have a custom `firstLabel` accessor method?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with using Instruments, but it shows allocations and no leaks. The usage is definitely something to do with `performSelectorOnMainThread:`, because if I don't call this and allocate the string anyway and `NSLog` it, memory usage doesn't creep up.

Comment: Try adding a new method to the class which sets the text of the label, call that method on the main thread instead of calling the label directly. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AnalysisTools/Reference/Instruments_User_Reference/AllocationsInstrument/AllocationsInstrument.html

Comment: OK, when I use @autoreleasepool and test on a device, everything is OK and memory doesn't grow. I'm only experiencing the growth on the simulator – is there any reason it wouldn't be the same?

Comment: It should be the same. There could be some version number or implementation detail difference. Trust the device over the simulator...

Answer (score 0):

Let's try:

```
- (void)counterTask {
@autoreleasepool {
    for (int i=0; i<5000000; i++) {
        if (i % 100 == 0) {
            [self.firstLabel performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setText:)
                                              withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i]
                                           waitUntilDone:YES];
        }
    }
}
[self.firstLabel performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setText:) withObject:@"finished." waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What happening in your loop that you are creating NSString and ARC add it to auto release pool.

not releases the memory(NSString*) immediately , will release later.

One more thing is that, actually performSelectorOnMainThread retains both target and objects.

So best way is that you create  nsstring instance after sending it to selector set it to nil so ARC will release it.

```
NSString* strText=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%d",i ];

    [self.firstLabel performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setText:)
                                      withObject:strText
                                   waitUntilDone:YES];
    strText=nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the suggested approach of @Wain should fix the issue.

But you may also use this:

```
- (void)counterTask {
    assert([NSThread currentThread] != [NSThread mainThread]);
    for (int i=0; i<5000000; i++) {
        if (i % 100 == 0) {
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                @autoreleasepool {
                    self.firstLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
                }
            });
        }
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue, ^{
        self.firstLabel.text = @"finished";
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

- (void)counterTask {

  **__weak NSString *str;**

  for (int i=0; i<50000; i++) {
      if (i % 100 == 0) {

  ```
      str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
      [self.logInTxtField performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setText:)
                                        withObject:str
                                     waitUntilDone:YES];
  }
  ```

  }

  [self.logInTxtField performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setText:) withObject:@"finished." waitUntilDone:NO];
  }